# Drupal: CCK ImageField, description not displaying

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

I've added the description field to my Image CCK Fields (in my nodes).
I filled the description field from back-end. However I dunno how to enable it in my front-end.

I cannot display the descriptions. I checked, they are not hided by css. The HTML element doesn't exist.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved with Custom Formatter module

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something you can enable in the UI, unless you're using a view.  You need to use a template file.  More info: http://drupal.org/node/432846

Comment: so the only way to use them is to add some php code in the template ? I want to display them under the images in my nodes.

Comment: Correct.  You need to use a template to display that text.

Comment: ok thanks. So, I've followed the istructions on the link you sent me, and created a new template (with the same name of the field: "field_myImage"). Nothing changing yet... I've update the cache. What am I missing ?

Comment: For this to work, you need both the original content-field.tpl.php and your modified copy content-field-field_image.tpl in your theme folder. Did you do this?